# PokeApi: criação mais rápida de uma lista de pokêmon

Tags: java, api, eclipse, maven, cliente-servidor

Estou querendo criar um programa que oferece informações sobre os pokêmon, utilizando o PokeApi, para ter acesso dos dados de cada criatura.

Eu estou fazendo esse programa atráves no eclipse, com auxilio do maven.

o `PokemonController.java` funciona como o controle, nele eu quero que ele pegue os dados de 500 pokemon e os salvem numa array.

```java
package br.com.pokemon.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.pokemon.command.findAll;
import br.com.pokemon.domain.pokemon;
import br.com.pokemon.domain.pokemonApi;
import br.com.pokemon.domain.pokemonSpecie;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.client.PokeApi;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.client.PokeApiClient;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.NamedApiResource;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.NamedApiResourceList;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.Pokemon;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.PokemonSpecies;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.PokemonSpeciesVariety;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.model.Type;

@Controller
public class PokemonController {

    @RequestMapping("/pokemon/image")
    public ModelAndView image() {
        ArrayList<Pokemon> pokemons = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();
        NamedApiResourceList na = pokemonApi.getApi().getPokemonList(0, 500);
        for(NamedApiResource n: na.getResults()) {
             Pokemon p = pokemonApi.getApi().getPokemon(n.getId());
             pokemons.add(p);
        }

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("pokemon/pokeimage");
        mav.addObject("pokemons", pokemons);
        return mav;

    }

}
```

o `pokeimage.jsp` seria a pagina que mostra as informações desses pokemons, por enquanto só o nome e a imagem de cada um, no entanto esse processo é demorado, devido a abertura da api, e leva + ou - 5 minutos pra página carregar

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${pokemons}" var="pokemon">
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png"></td>
            <td>${pokemon.name}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu queria saber se tem uma maneira de conseguir ler os dados dos pokemon de forma mais rápidas, já vi sites que fazem esse processo de forma mais eficientes e eficaz.

Eu criei um `pokemonApi.java` para abrir o pokeApi uma única vez e ser utilizado em todos os processos, tive a sensação de que o programa carrega mais rápido dessa maneira, mas não da forma desejada.

```java
package br.com.pokemon.domain;

import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.client.PokeApi;
import me.sargunvohra.lib.pokekotlin.client.PokeApiClient;

public class pokemonApi {

    private final static PokeApi pa = new PokeApiClient();

    public static PokeApi getApi() {
        return pa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lucas, essa pergunta está muito abrangente. Pelo que dá para ver no seu código, o seu gargalo são as requisições. Ao invés de fazer todas de uma vez, você espera cada uma terminar antes de fazer a próxima, e cada uma dessas requisições pode demorar até alguns segundos. Outra coisa que você poderia fazer também é realizar as requisições no lado do cliente, assim ele não precisa esperar por todas as requisições para poder visualizar as que já estão prontas, e suavizaria o processamento no lado do seu servidor também. Idealmente essa API deveria trazer todas as informações numa única requisição.

Comment: Algo que melhoraria muito sua performance era implementar um cache para os pokemons já pesquisados, acredito que as informações do pokemon não variam, então caso você já tenha pesquisado ele uma vez, não teria porque pesquisar novamente, pegando a informação do cache